# Haskell: Count Nodes of a Tree

Tags: haskell, count, functional-programming, tree, nodes

I have a custom Datatype:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
```

an example tree:

```
tree1 = Node 3 [Node 4 [Node 3 [], Node 2 []], Node 5 []]
```

and I am struggling while trying to create a function to count the Nodes of the tree.

I have a function:

```
numNodes :: Num p => Tree a -> p
numNodes(Node a []) = 0
numNodes(Node a b) = 1 + numNodes b
```

But that is not really working, where am I wrong?

Edit:
Compiler output:

```
   • Couldn't match type ‘Tree a’ with ‘[Tree a]’
      Expected type: [Tree a] -> p
        Actual type: Tree a -> p

   • Relevant bindings include
        numNodes :: [Tree a] -> p (bound at tree.hs:28:1)


28 | numNodes(Node a []) = 0
```

Comment: Should `numNodes` take a list of nodes or a single node? What does the compiler error message say?

Comment: hi, numNodes should take a tree like "tree1"

Comment: @Bergi I added de compiler output to the question

Comment: `b` is not a tree.

Comment: Your actual code includes a type signature, isn't it? Do include it too here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can't represent an empty tree with your data type; you can only represent a tree with a single node with no subtrees.

```
numNodes (Node a []) = 1
```

Second, each node as 0 or more *substrees* as children. You need to use `map` to compute the number of nodes in each subtree, then sum up the counts for each children.

```
numNodes (Node a b) = 1 + sum (map numNodes b)
```

Because `sum [] == 0` by definition, you don't actually need the base case, as `sum (map numNodes b)` will return the correct count whether or not `b` is non-empty.